# Next button + Javascript form manipulation result in problem on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

I have got a form with 2 dropdown lists on a simple HTML page. Depending on the value selected in the first dropdown list, a Javascript event handler(using the onChange event) changes the options of the second dropdown list.

When selecting a value in the first box and touching the second box in the browser window everything works fine, but when I use the "next" button provided by the dropdown-list-thing of Mobile Safari, only the rendered list changes, but the dropdown-list-thing shows still the old values. How can I fix this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I've since discovered this is indeed a bug in Mobile Safari. The HTML is updated but the picker view that is loaded up does not update it's values from when it first opens.

Comment: I used jQuery for it and the change event. I tested the code in desktop IE and firefox, but not on desktop safari, so I do not know whether it is specific to  the mobile edition, but it is definatly specific to safari.